# Aggregate and keep rows with NA

Tags: r, aggregate, na

What I want to do: arrange data by name and class, sort by year, calculate the mean of the values and keep the `valueMessage`.

Sample data:

```
name <- c("a", "a", "b", "b")
class <- c("c1", "c1", "c3", "c3")
year <- c("2010", "2010", "2008", "2008")
value <- c(100, 33, 100, 90)
valueMessage <-c(NA, "meh", NA, NA)

df <- data.frame(name, class, year, value, valueMessage)
df 


dat <- aggregate(df$value, list(year = df$year, name = df$name, class=df$class, valueMessage=df$valueMessage), mean)
dat <- dat[with(dat, order(class, name, year)), ]
```

Returns this:

```
year name class valueMessage  x
1 2010    a    c1          meh 33
```

But I would like it to keep the NA and return something like this:

```
year name class valueMessage  x
1 2010    a    c1          meh, NA 66.5
2 2008    b    c3          NA 95
```

Comment: So, are you expecting to end up with the same number of rows as you started with? Can you please post your expected output, because this isn't quite clear.

Comment: Yes, agree to @Ananda. In your example data it seems that aggregate actually does no aggregation, because there is only one value for each class/name/year combination.

Comment: You were right - I added a clearer example

Comment: great. You should probably delete the first one to clean up the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is that you're trying to do two different aggregations: one for your "value" column, and one for your "valueMessage" column.

If that's the case, you would have to do each separately and `merge` them, or look at using a package, like "data.table" to help out.

With "data.table", you can do the following:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df)
DT[, list(value = mean(value), 
          valueMessage = list(unique(valueMessage))), 
   by = list(year, name, class)]
#    year name class value valueMessage
# 1: 2010    a    c1  66.5       NA,meh
# 2: 2008    b    c3  95.0           NA
```

Note that the "valueMessage" column is a `list`. You could use `paste` if you wanted it to be a character vector instead. In other words:

```
DT[, list(value = mean(value), 
          valueMessage = paste(unique(valueMessage), collapse = ",")), 
   by = list(year, name, class)]
```

Here, I've assumed you're only interested in unique "valueMessage" values.

---

If you wanted to go with base R's `aggregate`, you could try something like the following:

```
M1 <- aggregate(value ~ year + name + class, df, mean)
M2 <- aggregate(as.character(valueMessage) ~ year + name + class,
                df, unique, na.action = na.pass)
merge(M1, M2)
```

I've used the "formula" method because I like the output better. `as.character(valueMessage)` was required because that column is presently a `factor`. The output of the `valueMessage` column would be, again, a `list`, but you can use an anonymous function and `paste` if you prefer a character vector of `length` 1 instead.

Comment: +1 Thank you for this interesting example. Didn't know that aggregate can handle a formula. Btw, `merge` is SQL `join`, `aggregate` is `group by` :-)

Answer (score 4):

I like to use `sqldf`, because SQL is such a nice, simple and intuitive way to do this (without need of knowing thousands of R functions and their specifics and gotchas):

```
require(sqldf)
sqldf('
select year, name, class, avg(value), 
       group_concat(distinct case when valueMessage is NULL 
                                  then "NA" 
                                  else valueMessage 
                             end) as valueMessages
from df
group by class, name, year
')
```

On your modified example it will produce this output:

```
  year name class avg(value) valueMessages
1 2010    a    c1       66.5        NA,meh
2 2008    b    c3       95.0            NA
```

Comment: Thanks! Works almost exactly the way I want. In my dataset, it could be the case that the same class/name/year combination has a different valueMessage. Any way to keep them all?

Comment: Nice example. Don't know much SQL myself, so always nice to see some examples. +1

Comment: @AnandaMahto yes, might not be for you if you come from different background. But SQL is time proven and was designed exactly for this type of operations. In R, it is sometimes pretty tricky to handle all those functions aggregate/tapply/ave/by/... with plenty of gotchas :) so I resort to easy and familiar SQL :-)

Answer (score 0):

A quick workaround, try this:

```
#convert NAs to "U"
x <- ifelse(is.na(df$valueMessage),"U",df$valueMessage)
df$valueMessage <- x
#aggregate
dat <- aggregate(df$value, list(year = df$year, name = df$name, class=df$class, valueMessage=df$valueMessage), mean)
dat <- dat[with(dat, order(class, name, year)), ]
#convert "U" back to NA
dat$valueMessage <- ifelse(dat$valueMessage=="U",NA,dat$valueMessage)
```

There must be more elegant way of doing this.